# Distinct values in cte table

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, databricks

I'm doing a query in SQL like this:

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        t.ktokk, t.txt30,
        case 
            when t.spras = 'P' then '1'
            when t.spras = 'E' then '2'
            else '3'
        end as ord_ktokk 
    from 
        t077y t 
    order by 
        ord_ktokk
)
select * 
from cte
```

and the result is that:

[Image]

[image: 1]

Now I want to select only the distinct values in `ktokk` column. How can i do that?
thanks for the help

Comment: why you need cte at all ? just do `select distinct ktokk from t077y`